# Sorting Columns PHP, football Stats

Tags: php, css

This is a football league with stats.  Right now the stats are just there.  We want to give the players an option to sort each stat to see who is the highest and lowest in each division.  I do not know how to get each table to sort (Descending, Ascending).  Ive been trying to figure it out forever, maybe someone can help.

```
    <h2>Passing Leaders</h2>
        <table class="style-std" id="passing-leaders-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Player</th>
            <th>&#35;</th>
            <th>Team</th>
            <th>Com</th>
            <th>Att</th>
            <th>Yd</th>
            <th>Td</th>
            <th>Int</th>
            <th>1p</th>
            <th>2p</th>
            <th>Dr</th>
            <th>Df</th>
            <th>Sk</th>
            <th>QBR</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <? foreach ($stats['passing'] as $row) : ?>
       <tr>
           <td><?=$row['name'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$row['number'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$row['team'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$row['completion'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$row['attempt'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$row['yard'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$row['touchdown'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$row['interception'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$row['1pat'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$row['2pat'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$row['drop'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$row['deflection'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$row['sack'] ?></td>
           <td><?=passer_rating($row) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <? endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. Depend on the client (Javascript)
2. Depend on the server

The amount of data you have, and whether or not you already have pagination and serverside code that drives the display is important.

If you use a javascript interface, then your code would be different --- you would reading the raw data and loading it into a table object.  There are many existing solutions for this using different javascript frameworks and libraries.  Many people who have simple apps, start with jquery and use one of the plugins for tabular data.  Here's just one of a gazillion jquery plugins you can use:  https://datatables.net/

In order for this to be optimal, you need to load ALL of your data, and it has to be a small enough data set that you can do this without killing a typical browser instance.

The backend/serverside method is typically based on passing a sort= parameter that is executed by clicking on a column.

```
 <th><a href=".?sort=player">Player</a></th>
```

You alter your script to utilize this $_GET parameter if it is passed.

Your query code needs to be rewritten so that if a sort parameter is provided, the query includes the appropriate ORDER BY in your SQL statement so you get the sortation you desire.

Again, frameworks, components and other re-usable pieces will save you a lot of time and trouble.

You asked a general question and I provided a general answer.  I should point out that since passer_rating() is a calculated column you won't be able to sort by that on the backend unless you can convert your calculation to be in the SQL itself.  Otherwise you should be able to accomplish this using either method.